# How can I get Information about every PCs in domain using C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dns, active-directory

Is possible to get information like PC name or amount of RAM for every PCs in domain? If not what should I use to have possibility to do that.

Comment: Take a look at *WMI* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page).  You can access this from C# using the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure` namespace.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/retrieving-an-instance

Comment: This is kind of a broad question. You can use WMI or PowerShell to gather remote computer information. What specifically are you stuck on?